# IntelliJ python development environment

Tags: python, intellij-idea

Here's my python development directory structure

`.
├── dirs
│   ├── dir1
│   │   └── a.py
│   ├── dir2
│   │   ├── ab.py
│   │   ├── cc.py
├── py_lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── dir3
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── abc.py
│   ├── dir4
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── abc_ccc.py`

In `a.py`, I need to import things from `abc_ccc.py` that is in `py_lib/dir4`.  How do I setup the IntelliJ development environment?

Well, the truth is `py_lib` is our library directory.  Is there any specific setting in IntelliJ to address this sort of directory structure?

Comment: Can you confirm that you’re using IntelliJ, not Pycharm?

Comment: Yes.  I'm using IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would use IntelliJ for your Python project. In PyCharm you can add `py_lib` as another `Content Root` to your project.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html

Otherwise, package your library and install it in your venv